# How to avoid race condition in UITableView reloadData?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I got a problem: I should totally reload data in a table view sometimes really frequently. So I call realoadData before previous realod operation finished and getting index out of bounds exception. As far as I know there is no way to determine if data reloading finished or not.

I could put a delay before reloading, but I think that's the ugly way.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You should check out NSoperations.

Answer (score 0):

A "reload phase" don't overlap with others and it get executed on the main thread only.

What you are probably facing is that you are sending `reloadData` messages faster than
they can be processed, and thus get enqueued in the run loop. There's no reason to send such messages faster than the display update frequency. So yes, restricting the maximum update frequency to something like `display_frequency/N` will be key.

See also: [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)